# Hungerford Page 153 Corollary 5.6

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, notation

I don't understand what this theorem is saying:

$\textbf{Corollary 5.6}$ If $\phi:R\to S$ is a homomorphism of commutative rings and $s_1,...,s_n\in S$, then the map $R[x_1,...,x_n]\to S$ given by $f\mapsto\phi f(s_1,...,s_n)$ is a homomorphism of rings.

This is a corollary of the UMP for $R[x_1,...,x_n]$ (which I don't think I need to state here) which the proof of does not answer my question (Hungerford doesn't really prove 5.6, he just references the proof of 5.5 in which he just says its obvious).

The only problem I am having is that I have no idea what $\phi f(s_1,...,s_n)$ is: by Hungerfords definitions, $f:\mathbb{N}^n\to R$ but I don't see how $(s_1,...,s_n)$ is supposed to be in $\mathbb{N^n}$, it seems more like $(s_1,...,s_n)\in S^n$. I do see how we can (albeit somewhat colloquially) take $f(s_1,...,s_n)$ to be an element of $S$, but then I don't know what $\phi f(s_1,...,s_n)$ would be (given that $\phi:R\to S$, $\phi$ does not really map things in $S$).

I feel like I understood a variant of this UMP at one point from reading Altman Kleinman's $\textit{A Term of Commutative Algebra}$, but Hungerford's exposition here just makes no sense to me. Can someone please very carefully and explicitly/precisely explain what this map $R[x_1,...,x_n]\to S$ actually is?

(You can assume I know everything in Hungerford's $\textit{ Algebra}$ up unitl page 153 if it helps).

(Note: there is an MSE page on a very similar note but it does not at all answer the question I am asking).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation is explained explicitly on Page 152, two paragraphs before the statement of Theorem 5.5 (which also uses the notation):

> Let $\varphi\colon R\to S$ be a homomorphism of rings, $f\in R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, and $s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_n\in S$. By Theorem 54. $f=\sum\limits_{i=0}^m a_ix_1^{k_{i1}}\cdots x_n^{k_{in}}$ with $a_i\in R$ and $k_{ij}\in\mathbb{N}$. Omit all $x_i$ that appear with exponent zero. Then $\varphi f(s_1,\ldots,x_n)$ **is defined to be**
> $$\sum_{i=0}^n \varphi(a_i)s_1^{k_{i1}}\cdots s_n^{k_{in}}\in S;$$
> that is $\varphi f(s_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is obtained by substituting $\varphi(a_i)$ for $a_i$, and $s_i^{k_{ij}}$ for $x_i^{k_{ij}}$ ($k_{ij}\gt 0$). [emphasis added]

The restriction to $k_{ij}\gt 0$ is because he is not assuming $S$ has a unity, so $s^0$ need not be defined.

Comment: I have no idea how I missed that. Thank you!